# Gridview displaying only 12 images in android

Tags: android

I am having a gridView with each item having an image to be loaded. I have used adapter to render the image. I am assigning images as gridView items using resource ID array created using images in drawable folder.

The problem is gridView is being displayed with only 12 images(which fits the view without scrolling). I have around 40 images resource ID in that array. the getView is called only 12-13 times.

Could you pleae help me how to display all 40 images on grid view? Do i need to explicitly add scrollpane in grid.xml?

Below is the grid.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/wooden_background"
         android:id="@+id/RootView">
         <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxWidth="150dip"
            android:maxHeight="150dip" >

        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the getView function inside adapter

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi;
    if (convertView == null){  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_image,parent, false);
    }
    else{
        vi=convertView;
    }
        /*imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(170,170));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);*/

    System.out.println("Inside getView");
    ImageView image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image.setMaxHeight(150);
    image.setMinimumHeight(150);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY );
    image.setImageResource(imageIngredientsID[position]);

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question adding the getView function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many items the gridview gets depends entirely on your getCount() method in your adapter, what does it return? 12?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I had made a silly mistake. i had set the count to old static array which had the length 12 and hence it was displaying only 12 images. thanks a lot for this hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ScrollView` to the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/wooden_background"
     android:id="@+id/RootView">
     <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxWidth="150dip"
        android:maxHeight="150dip" >

    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```